# Web deploy 2.0 can't enable Windows Authentication?

Tags: iis, webdeploy

Before i write a powershell script to enable Windows Authentication, I just want to make sure web deploy cannot already do this. Can someone confirm this?

Overview of web deploy: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/426/overview-of-web-deploy/

Answer (score 1):

For Web Deploy, Windows authentication has to be preinstalled separately on the server (see the [requirements and limitations](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569074%28WS.10%29.aspx) page for Web Deploy).

A typical scenario in a Web Deploy deployment operation would be that the source server has Windows auth installed but the destination server does not. In this case, Web Deploy cannot install Windows auth for you on the destination server. If the server is Windows Server 2008 (running IIS 7), you would have to install the Windows authentication role service first.

Having said that, here is one option you might look into: if you do write a script to install the Windows authentication role service, you could run that script by using the preSync switch on the Web Deploy command line. The preSync switch lets you specify a command or batch file to run on the destination before the main Web Deploy synchronization operation begins. For more information, see the **preSync** entry on the [Web Deploy Operation Settings](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569089%28WS.10%29.aspx) page and the related information on the [Web Deploy runCommand Provider](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee619740%28WS.10%29.aspx) page.